# Bootstrap vertical center container in footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to create a footer for my first page in Bootstrap and it looks fine except the contents should be centered vertically. After inspecting the elements in Chrome, it looks like the actual container element is about 50% the height of the parent footer element.

Now I was able to partially fix this by setting the "line-height" to match the "height" property of the footer, but when doing so, it caused part of the contents to appear well below the footer. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Without Line-Height:

[image]

With Line-Height:

[image]

```
<!-- Site footer -->
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>
                <a href="#">Home</a> | <a href="#">About Us</a> | <a href="#">Contact</a>
                <br />
                © Website 2016. All rights reserved.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p class="muted pull-right">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i id="social-fb" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com"><i id="social-tw" class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://plus.google.com"><i id="social-gp" class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                    <a href="mailto:website@gmail.com"><i id="social-em" class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
footer
{
    height: 100px;
    background:#fff;
    margin-top:20px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` + `align-items:center` to achieve that.

```
footer
{
    height: 100px;
    background:#fff;
    margin-top:20px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0uqew3t/)

Comment: That is perfect, was not aware of either of those! The icons on the right seem to align more with the top line of text than vertically center itself but its close enough! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use table properties for vertical alignment.

HTML:

```
<!-- Site footer -->
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>
                <a href="#">Home</a> | <a href="#">About Us</a> | <a href="#">Contact</a>
                <br />
                © Website 2016. All rights reserved.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p class="muted pull-right">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i id="social-fb" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com"><i id="social-tw" class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://plus.google.com"><i id="social-gp" class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                    <a href="mailto:website@gmail.com"><i id="social-em" class="fa fa-envelope-square fa-2x social"></i></a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
    background:#fff;
    margin-top:20px;
}

footer p {
    margin: 0;
}

footer .container .row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

footer .container .row > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/62shy0ob/1

Comment: The working example you linked still has the contents at the top of the footer rather than vertically centered for me

Answer (score 0):

Try adding padding-top and padding-bottom instead of line-height:

```
footer
{
    height: 100px;
    background:#fff;
    padding: 2% 0;

}
```